# How to get information about active user interaction with an application?

Tags: linux, process

I don't know if the title makes sense, but basically I am trying to write an app that tracks the amount of time specific applications run and/or used. The first half was (how long they actually run) was easy, but I am clueless on how to approach to the second issue.

I thought, one obvious approach would be to asses interaction based on whether the application GUI is displayed on screen and or reduced. I think there is an MacOS application (usage) that does this. How do you actually access this information?

I am not really experienced in low level stuff, but I have plenty of time (6 weeks) to figure this out, so any suggestions (or even direction for a better search terminology) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: What I am looking for here: Any suggestion how I should approach this, maybe an existing tool/program that would help me get this information,
or even a pretty general advice on where(on what domain) I should focus on for an answer.

Also I got negged and sent here by StackOverFlow

Comment: Right now this sounds more like a programming question (for [so]) than a U&L question, but I'm not certain exactly what it is you're looking for (e.g. seeking an existing tool that tracked this information would be on-topic). You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: This sounds related to "process accounting". I don't know exactly how this is done on macOS or Linux, but you may want to look it up.

Comment: What OS is this for: MacOS, Gnu/Linux or both (your question suggests both).